# What's the exact time for "a short amount of time" requirement for triggering chat room?

Tags: support, comments, chat

When I was reading the *newest* announcement regarding chat rooms at:

https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/74243/777820

I noticed

> 2011-06-10: When adding a new comment to a post with many comments between two users in a short time, a link is provided to create a chat room to continue the conversation.

What is the exact time used for 'in a short time'?

Comment: Note that according to the [current faq](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/19757/369802) (at the bottom, under miscellaneous) it states the prompt is given if two users exchange at least 4 pairs of back-and-forth comments. It says nothing about time anymore, so it may well be there currently is no 'short time' parameter in play anymore.

Comment: That's a very old statement, it's no longer true.

Comment: How do you define "announcement regarding chat rooms"? You linked to the entry for the first half of 2011, but chat were also mentioned in younger entries.

Comment: _Short amount of time_ probably means 6 to 8 minutes in this context :)

Comment: @Tinkeringbell I'm pretty sure it's three back and forth comments and I'm also pretty sure it does get canceled. I actually tried it with 2 accounts. Even more confusing, if during the back and forth comments, another user also comments (e.g., thus breaking the chain). It won't trigger...

Comment: @Mast I've once read the condition to trigger the chat room and after a few days, the option is no longer there (in 2020). So I think it should still be there...

Comment: @P.Mort.-forgotClayShirky_q I've gone through the entire history in that post. The quote was the only one regarding triggering the option.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ I just tried again. And after 20 minutes it's still there. So not 6~8 minutes I guess...

Comment: @CosmosZhu well, then I hope you'll get an answer soon, and we can update the FAQ :) (btw, the 6-8 from πάνταῥεῖ refers to https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/19514/369802 )